# iOS AppID Start With *

Tags: ios

When I create a wildcard AppID on developer website, Apple says *Please enter a valid Identifier*:

[image]

I'm pretty sure there is no space in BundleID field and don't have same ID in this account. Actually, I create * in another account about a few month ago. Does Apple change the rules?

Comment: Well, you ought to use the asterisk as the _last_ component, so just a single one won't work. Use "com.mycompany.*" or something

Comment: Emmmm....I don't think so. And I find it just couldn't create on UI. I use `fastlane spaceship` solve this problem.

```ruby
Spaceship::Portal.login('YourAppleID', nil)
Spaceship::Portal.select_team
Spaceship::Portal::App.create!(bundle_id: "*", name: "All")
```

Thanks anyway. 

Answer (score 0):

I find it just couldn't create on UI. I use `fastlane spaceship` solve this problem.

```
Spaceship::Portal.login('YourAppleID', nil)
Spaceship::Portal.select_team
Spaceship::Portal::App.create!(bundle_id: "*", name: "All")
```